# How to restore OEM software after upgrade from Vista to WIndows 8 on Notebook, Aspire 6935G

Tags: windows-8, acer-aspire

Recently I upgraded my notebook from Vista home premium to windows 8 pro, now after updating  most of the preinstalled programs by Acer, I've found out they are not restored as before. For example, I can't access my **hidden hard disk drive utility, finger print scanner**, etc.

Please tell me how to restore all these programs by Acer on Windows 8 pro which were originally available when I purchased my notebook with Vista.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do would be to search [Acer's support website](http://support.acer.com/us/en/default.aspx) to see if they have Windows 8 updates available for your particular laptop model

As it sounds like you have discovered, some of the Vista software is likely not compatible with Windows 8.  This makes sense as Vista was released almost 5 years ago, which in software terms is close to an eternity, and Windows 8 is a major update.

**Edit:** I see that you had added the model information to your question.  That's a rather old model.  Acer may not provide Windows 8 compatible software.

If that's the case, you can try and search for drivers and software from the individual device manufacturers (e.g. the finger print reader).  You may be able to determine the manufacturer via the device properties in Device Manager, and then try searching their website.

Comment: I did search on it. my model is eligible for upgrade, even wrote a mail on support center but no reply from them that is why i made contact on this site. Thanx anyway for ur reply. but still looking forward for a solution to my problem.

Comment: @Rocky What specific laptop model do you have?  I'm not saying to check if your laptop model is upgradeable to Windows 8.  What I'm suggesting is that Acer (not Microsoft) will likely have specific downloads for your laptop for Windows 8.

Comment: I have Acer Aspire 6935G model. i tried to find solution on Acer website but couldn't anything helpful.

Comment: i bought this model in June 2009 with Vista Home Premium 32-bit & this model was latest at that time........:(

Comment: @Rocky - You will need to contact Acer on solutions to restore the factory image.  Your finger print scanner should have generic drivers that work.

Comment: Thanx Ramhound, i can restore my notebook to windows vista anytime but i want all these systems to work with windows 8 pro. also my C drive is around 55GB full with windows only. how i can make it less heavy?

Comment: @Rocky Maybe you could try installing the Acer Updater located at http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=6&modelId=573?  In general, if they've not updated the software to work with Win8, you may be out of luck.